# Git: Preventing Commit During a Rebase

Tags: git, bash, macos, rebase

I know how to easily 'fix' this state, when I've accidentally done a `git commit --amend` during an interactive rebase. But I'm wondering if anyone has a solution, of any level of complexity, that would allow me to configure git/terminal/bash to PREVENT me from being able to do this.

I'm just using Mac OSX Terminal. I'd be open to other terminal programs if the solution required them.

```
1 @: master$ git pull
2 @: master$ git checkout my/feature/branch
3 @: my/feature/branch$ git rebase -i master
// There are merge conflicts
// I fix them, then
4 @: my/feature/branch$ git add .
// Then what I should do is:
5correct @: my/feature/branch$ git rebase --continue
// But instead, just due to dumb muscle memory, I do:
5incorrect @: my/feature/branch$ git commit --amend
```

I can easily fix the broken resulting state. I'm just trying to figure out if there's a way I can configure something to PREVENT me from ever being able to execute the 5incorrect command if I'm in the middle of a rebase.

Comment: Not really. You can use a bash alias to run something other than `git` itself when you enter `git ...`, and in that alias / function / script, check if you are in a rebase and whether you want to allow some other command—but it's *normal* to do amends and/or additional commits during interactive rebase, to split commits. (Note: a trick with bash is that `command foo` runs the actual foo instead of your alias, so you use that *in* your alias when needed.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following local pre-commit hook as `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
shopt -s extglob

if [[ -d `git rev-parse --git-path rebase-merge` \
   || -d `git rev-parse --git-path rebase-apply` ]]; then
  read -p 'Rebase in progress, continue? '
  [[ ${REPLY,,} == @(y|yes) ]]
fi
```

Then just `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit` and you're sorted. If a rebase is in progress, then you'll be prompted to continue or otherwise press ctrl-c or just enter or what's handier for you, and the script/commit will stop.